# Django rest framework: How to change error response format globally

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-validation

All the error messages return from django default validators ends with a dot (.). Is there anyway to remove that last dot from all messages globally.

Or, If someone help me to find a way to catch these error returning function, I can trim the last dot if exists in that section.

Sample error messages.

```
{
  "email": [
    "This field may not be blank."
  ]
}


{
  "email": [
    "Enter a valid email address."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change all of them, you should override the field's default messages somewhere in the application initialization:

```
serializers.CharField.default_error_messages['blank'] = 'This field may not be blank'
```

For example, the blank message can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L727)

Comment: It works. But I need to add this to my all serializer. Is there anyway to configure it globally?

Comment: sure, the serializers in the above code sample should be the one from rest_framework and it'll be applied to *every* CharField.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Restframework's exception handler. Please have a [look](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).